How can I fix the rendering of these glyphs in stix2?
I have the MWE below, where I'm trying to get stix2 fonts to work with the other packages, but there seems to be a conflict. How can I resolve this and why is it happening?
Using lualatex compiler in overleaf for this example, but originally had the issue with my own local install of texlive.
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}


\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix2}

\usepackage{siunitx}       % needed for units
\usepackage{fontspec}      % without this, test 3 fails, with this, test 2 fails

\begin{document}

Tests: 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Must work with character: ä
    \item This equation should be a minus b divided by infinity:
\begin{equation}
    a-b/\infty
\end{equation}
    \item This unit should be the microsecond: \si{\micro\second}
\end{enumerate}

This is the font. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Math font:

\begin{equation}
    \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\end{equation}

\end{document}

I think I need fontenc for use with stix2
sinuitx I need for the units in my work
fontspec seems to be the main issue in that I need to use it for the mu symbol to display correctly in microseconds for example, but with it the code evaluates to:

and without it the code evaulates to:

Where in the first image the equation in test 2 is incorrect, and in the second image the mu symbol in test 3 has been replaced with another glyph. How do I resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

never use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} with luatex

The siunitx package defines \micro as \siunitx_declare_prefix:Nnx \micro { -6 } { \__siunitx_unit_non_latin:n { "03BC } } which is an upright mu. The stix2 font doesn't have that character.
You can either redefine it to be italic \mu, which stix2 does have, or redefine it to an upright mu from a different font, for example using the upgreek package (which takes the symbols from the Euler font by default).
The following MWE shows both approaches:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{stix2}

\usepackage{siunitx}       % needed for units
\DeclareSIPrefix\micro{\mu}{-6}

\begin{document}

Tests: 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Must work with character: ä
    \item This equation should be a minus b divided by infinity:
\begin{equation}
    a-b/\infty
\end{equation}
    \item This unit should be the microsecond: \si{\micro\second}
\DeclareSIPrefix\micro{\upmu}{-6}
    \item This unit should be the microsecond: \si{\micro\second}
\end{enumerate}

This is the font. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Math font:

\begin{equation}
    \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\end{equation}

\end{document}


Note that you don't need fontenc.
Another small change is the Adobe Symbol font for upgreek, for a different mu that might be a bit more stix-like:
\usepackage[Symbol]{upgreek}




\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}


\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}       % needed for units
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

Tests: 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Must work with character: ä
    \item This equation should be a minus b divided by infinity:
\begin{equation}
    a-b/\infty
\end{equation}
    \item This unit should be the microsecond: \si{\micro\second}
\end{enumerate}

This is the font. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Math font:

\begin{equation}
    \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\end{equation}

\end{document}

or using STIX for text as well, adding
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}



Thanks, this is an elegant solution - however the text font and math font appear more consistent with the Marijn's approach

@aleks you only asked about math. You can choose a suitable Times-like text font with \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} or \setmainfont{STIX Two Text} I updated the answer with a stix version
